# Какие есть методы поиска источника ошибок на сайтах с кучей запутанного legacy кода?

Tags: javascript, css

Помогаю в доработке сайта который работает достаточно давно и имеет кучу запутанного legacy кода с нулевой документацией. По файловой структуре крайне сложно понять, что делает конкретный модуль. Есть ряд открытых баг-репортов по фронт-енду.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то методы для локализации источников ошибок на сайте. К примеру, сообщают что в определенном диве текст вылазит за рамки или отображается не та информация. Как понять какой из css или js может отвечать за данный элемент?

Comment: с css все просто - в консоли браузера каждое правило подписано, какой файл какая строчка. С js уже сложнее

Comment: Думаю стоит конкретизировать используемые фреймворки. Допустим на backend используется C#, можно начать с различных анализаторов кода (опять же не ясна цель поиска ошибок). C frontend процесс тоже зависит от архитектуры фреймворка. Возможно просто по stacktrace и дебагом выяснить ничего не удастся.